# Is setting Priority Hint fetchpriority=low for favicon.svg and/or site.webmanifest a good idea for website speed / Core Web Vitals?

Tags: performance, page-speed, favicon, headers, core-web-vitals

I've noticed in a `chromium` desktop browser web console that the default priority (`fetchpriority`) for `favicon.svg` and `site.webmanifest` as assigned by the browser is `high`.

Would it be a good idea to set `fetchpriority=low` for these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome *should* (without any specification set) load SVG documents one-at-a-time in the layout-blocking phase, and fetch them with a priority of `low`. See the table on Web.dev's page about priority hints that shows [how most resources are currently prioritized and sequenced in Chrome](https://web.dev/priority-hints/).

However, priority computation logic can be affected by many factors such as the order that resources are referenced in your HTML. I'd imagine your favicon and webmanifest occur very early. Perhaps that's why. I would test it.

The combined file size of both ought to be very small in the first place, though. So I find it unlikely that you would see a significant difference in your Core Web Vitals scores by setting their `fetchpriority` to `low`.

Personally, I would let the browser decide and save these hints for more exceptional cases. In general, I recommend using the resource hint sparingly, as over use can result in degrading performance.

A scenario where it would be objectively worth while is when you have an image presented above the fold (think LCP) and want to signal that it's important to your UX early in the loading process. So you'd set `fetchpriority` to `high`.